# How to using telegram bot send a request to my server?

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

I have a requirement that I need to use tg bot to create a form to my service.

I have read the documentation of tg, I know that you can use api webhook or getUpdates to get the information sent to the chat room.

(https://core.telegram.org/api)

But that is not enough to meet my needs, I need to be able to send a specific request from the tg bot to my URL query, I can't even post google.com now, what is wrong with my settings.